# Maven task run using Ant

Tags: java, maven, ant

Spec: Maven 3.5.0,jdk1.7,Ant 1.9

Example:-

```
mvn install:install-file 
    -Dfile=C:/temp/DEPLOY/xyzSearchpdf.jar   
    -DgroupId=org.xyz.search.pdf  
    -DartifactId=org.xyz 
    -Dversion=2.5 
    -Dpackaging=jar
```

**Question : How to run this Maven command using Ant**

Reason : I could use this Ant-Target for Customized Jars to be deployed to Maven-Repo for bundling along with actual apps.

Currently i have Batch file  to run every time for deployment of Customized jars to Maven -repo.

Comment: The question is why do you need to do this from Ant ? Why not using the artifact as a dependency which will then being downloaded from Maven?

Comment: Hi, "Custom built Jars to be deployed to Maven-Repo" ...Is this possible to down Load via Maven  from Internet ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Customer built jars to be deployed to Maven-Repo" ? And furthermore ...download via Maven from Internet? The example you have given is a usual dependency log4j-api is already existent in Maven Central...can you give more detailed information what are you trying to solve / What the real problem is?

Comment: Sir... I just gave an example and in followup had this " I could use this Ant-Target for Customized Jars to be deployed to Maven-Repo"...  from the original ask for.... :(

Comment: Hi I have a Custom built jar ...xyzSearchpdf.jar, can some one advise me how to port this jar into a local Maven/repo folder ???  using Ant commands.

Comment: Best is to deploy that jar into repository manager and afterwards use it as a usual dependency...And another recommended step would be to migrate the build of that jar as well to Maven...

Comment: >> deploy that jar into repository manager  .... This is Exactly I intend to do using ANT target , but  for the above script , need Ant equivalent.... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to call Maven from Ant (http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/mvn.html):

```
  <artifact:mvn pom="path/to/my-pom.xml" mavenHome="/path/to/maven-2.0.x">
    <arg value="install:install-file"/>
  </artifact:mvn>
```

You can also use Ant exec to execute any command line task:

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Comment: Hi I am getting BUILD FAILED with the following error  using " Ant exec "

[exec] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
     [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [exec] [INFO] Total time: 0.089 s
     [exec] [INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-20T00:27:44+05:30
     [exec] [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/243M
     [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [exec] [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory ......

Comment: Hi  Do we need pom.xml for executing  the maven command  ex:- mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\temp\<deploy.jar> -DgroupId=<groupid>  -DartifactId=<artifactid> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar       If i need to use Ant with exec to simpfly the process. how could this be done.